# ExtraStrings Android

Tags: android, listview

Im trying to get a string from a input dialog from an activity and then I want to add this string to a listview in another activity. But I can't. This is my code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Nombre de la cotización");

            final EditText input = new EditText(this);

            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            builder.setView(input);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    nombre_cot = input.getText().toString();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CotizacionesActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("nombre",nombre_cot);

                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
```

And this is the other code:

```
public void obtenerNombre(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    nombre = extras.getString("nombre");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, list_cotizaciones);
    list_cotizaciones.add(nombre);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lvCotizacion.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing these lines:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, list_cotizaciones);
list_cotizaciones.add(nombre);
//adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
lvCotizacion.setAdapter(adapter);
```

..into these:

```
list_cotizaciones.add(nombre);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_cotizaciones);
//adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
lvCotizacion.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In your original code, you're adding a new item into your list *after* you create the adapter. That approach won't work because your adapter isn't bounded to your list - it will have no idea about your list and whether or not it got updated.

Also, when creating an `ArrayAdapter`, you're supposed to pass a resource ID to a `TextView`, not to your layout. Refer to these codes specifically:

```
// Wrong - passes android.R.layout.activity_list_item
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, list_cotizaciones);

// Correct - passes android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_cotizaciones);
```

Comment: The logcat says "You must supply a resource ID for a TextView"

Comment: Can you post your entire `LogCat`? I don't see any `TextView` in the code you posted above. It could've been from a different part of your app.

Comment: 06-24 01:49:52.790  17765-17765/com.example.alumno_j.movilesproy E/ArrayAdapter﹕ You must supply a resource ID for a TextView


06-24 01:49:52.830  17765-17765/com.example.alumno_j.movilesproy E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: Maybe it's something with the input??

Comment: No. When creating an `ArrayAdapter` you should pass a resource ID to a `TextView`, not your layout. I've revised my answer, note the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in the corrected code above.

Comment: Hey ridsatrio, I have another question. How I can storage items of the listview because when I pass a new string the other string in the listview disappears

Answer (score 0):

You need to give resourceId for ArrayAdapter. `android.R.layout.activity_list_item` layout requires to set textView resourceId `android.R.id.text1`.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item, list_cotizaciones);
```

replace with

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1, list_cotizaciones);
```